# AWS pipeline, code deploy 'Tags cannot be empty'."

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

"When attempting to create an AWS pipeline, I am encountering an issue where it fails during the Codedeploy phase and presents the error message: 'Tags cannot be empty'."

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix the issue by editing my **taskdef.json** and remove `"tags": []`

Answer (score 0):

This is normal when deployment group associated with pipeline does not have any tags associated with it. Add one or more tags to your deployment group in the AWS CodeDeploy console:

- go to the CodeDeploy console
- choose the deployment group associated with pipeline - edit
- scroll down to the "Tags" section and add tags - save changes

After adding the tags, rerun your pipeline again.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, I did that, but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: @TeuddyR where you able to fix? I encountered it now

Answer (score 0):

When you look at groups to deploy to CodeDeploy, you can choose to deploy to EC2, autoscaling groups, or ECS/Lambda.

You use an AWS resource tag to specify the target for deployment, but it doesn't appear to be specified, or if it is, there is no target resource.